# How to find A, B, C from equation mapping.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sir, Help me to find A,B and C when

$$\frac{A}x+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x-1}=\frac{x-2}{x^2(x-1)}$$

I try to do.

$(x(x-1)+(x-1)+x^2)/(x^2(x-1)) = (x-2)/(x^2(x-1))$

But I do not how to map A,B,C with coefficient. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: How have $A,B,C$ vanished in the second line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of simplifying & solving the result of [Partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). As [lab bhattacharjee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33337/lab-bhattacharjee)'s comment stated, you forgot to include the $A, B, C$ factors when you tried to solve the equation. Specifically, putting the left hand side (LHS) fractions each under a common denominator of $x^2(x-1)$, the numerator sum of the LHS must equal the numerator of the RHS. This gives by simplifying and putting items with the same power of $x$ together

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
A(x)(x-1) + B(x - 1) + C(x^2) & = x - 2 \\
Ax^2 - Ax + Bx - B + Cx^2 & = x - 2 \\
(A + C)x^2 + (B - A)x - B & = x - 2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

The powers of $x$ terms must match on both sides for it to be true for all $x$, so you get

$$A+C = 0 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$B - A = 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

$$-B = -2 \implies B = 2 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

This is a system of $3$ linear equations in $3$ unknowns. In this case, you can solve them quite easily by substituting \eqref{eq4A} into \eqref{eq3A} to get $A = 1$, then substituting this into \eqref{eq2A} to get $C = -1$.

Comment: Dear John Omielan, So can I use same concept to find $(x^2+16x+18)/(x^3+2x^2-15x-36) = A/(x-4) + B/(x+3) + C/((x+3)^2)$ ? , thanks.

Comment: You're welcome for the help. As for your second comment, you can use the same concept. In particular, since $x^3 + 2x^2 - 15x - 36 = (x-4)(x+3)^2$, to get each of the terms on the right to use the same denominator, you $\frac{A}{x-4}\left(\frac{(x+3)^2}{(x+3)^2}\right) = \frac{A(x+3)^2}{(x-4)(x+3)^2}$. Likewise, multiply the $B$ fraction numerator by $(x-4)(x+3)$ and $C$ by $x-4$ to get $x^2 + 16x + 18 = A(x+3)^2 + B(x-4)(x+3) + C(x-4)$. Expand and equation powers of $x$ on both sides, similar to what I did in my answer, & you'll get $3$ linear eq. in $3$ unknowns you can solve for $A,B,C$.

Comment: Dear, Thank again.

Comment: @joenpcnpcsolution I made a small mistake in my original answer write up where I mixed the $A$ and $C$ values around originally. However, I've corrected this now, with there appearing to not be any more mistakes. Nonetheless, please double-check & let me know if you see anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

As $$Ax(x-1)+B(x-1)+Cx^2=x-2$$ is an identity

set $x=0$ to find $-B=0-2$

Set $x=1$ to find $C=1-2$

Set $x=-1$